# Update App Launcher Badge Count in Android App Icon

Tags: android

Currently, in my app, I need to show the total jsonArray count as the notification badge count in the app icon, the count is shown when I used Notification, now I need to update that count value programmatically from an activity.

I've used the [Shortcut Badger Library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger). The value is updated programmatically till android version Lollipop but the badge is not shown in devices above Lollipop

```java
public static void notificationBadgeCounter(Context context, int count)
{

    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, count);
    BagdeUtils.setBadgeCount(context,count);
}
```

Also, I tried the following code but this code has no any effect

```java
public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, int count) {
    String launcherClassName = getLauncherName(context);
    if (launcherClassName == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public static String getLauncherName(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried many links and solutions available in StackOverflow but none of them worked. Can anyone relate some solutions or any sort of library? 
Any sort of help would be appreciatable.

Thank you !!